# Infinite stream without elements

Tags: stream, scheme, lisp, racket, infinite

We just learned about streams in one of my programming courses. I worked my way already through this weeks assigned tasks except this one: Define an infinite stream that has no elements. I already scimmed through the 3.5 chapter of the SICP book but I still not really get what the trick is. Some hints would be awesome ty ^^

Comment: What does it mean for an infinite stream to have no elements? Then it's not infinite.

Comment: y that would be my intuition aswell however the assignment says exactly that "Define an infinite stream that has no elements"

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the instructor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the exact type of streams you are using.

Basically there are two different types of streams:

```
- empty streams
- streams consisting of an element followed by an stream
```

Therefore you need two different types of values to represent the two types.

In SICP ([sicp](/questions/tagged/sicp)) they write:

> *There is a distinguishable object, `the-empty-stream`, which cannot be
>   the result of any `cons-stream` operation, and which can be identified
>   with the predicate `stream-null?`*

One way to define a distinguishable (unique) object in Scheme is to allocate 
an new cons cell - its address is unique to that cell.

```
(define the-empty-stream (list 'this-is-the-empty-stream))
(define (stream-null? x) (eq? x the-empty-stream))
```

In Racket one would simply use a struct to represent the empty stream

```
(struct the-empty-stream ())
(define stream-null? the-empty-stream?)
```

Functions such as `stream->list` need to handle both types of lists.

Back to your question: If you are using SICP streams the answer is simple.
The expression `the-empty-stream` will give you an empty stream.

If you are defining your own, you will need to choose a way to represent 
an empty stream - and then carefully modify all the stream functions you
have to handle the empty stream too.